# Page upside down?

Tags: rotating

I have a quite wide table in my document, that I would like to display "rotated". Everything seems fine, but apparently there is some problem towards the end: when I try to print out (print to file) I get the rotated page upside down.

Is there a way to solve the issue?

(Latex->dvi2ps->ps2pdf->View PDF (I use Texmaker))

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[]{rotating}
\usepackage[]{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\fancyplain{}{\textbf{\textit{\leftmark}}}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\fancyplain{}{\textbf{\thepage}}}
\fancyfoot[]{}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}

\begin{document}
Normal page.
\clearpage
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \textbf{Bla Bla Bla} & 01/01/2009 & 01/01/2010 & \\ 
\hline \textbf{Abcd efc} & Something something & Little bit longer description for something.\\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\caption{Something.}
\end{sidewaystable}
\clearpage
Another normal page.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is standard for the `sidewaystable` to rotate the table by 90 degrees. However, it could be a setting on your printer when duplexing? If you create a 3-page document *without* the `sidewaystable`, does the second page still get printed upside down? I say printer, but I think it would be the same if you were to "save to file."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I try a "print to file" operation on any other three pages of my document, I get them with the correct orientation. In some way the page is like a landscape in PDF and this creates some problems. Is there a way to rotate only the table, while keeping the page with its normal, portrait orientation? Since I will not be there when they print it, I don't want my "book" to have an upside down page :)

Comment: You should compile your document directly to PDF using `pdflatex`, as opposed to `latex` -> `dvips` -> `ps2pdf`. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: 1. `something.\\ ` misses a ` & ` :  `something. & \\ `
2. Directly pdflatex-ing your code (TeXLive 2011) does *not* rotate the page. Could you try that?

Comment: I guess it would work, since already two of you suggested it! Anyway I modified the ps2pdf call as suggested by Werner since I have many eps files. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two options to fix this behaviour.

1. `ps2pdf` automatically rotates landscape-like pages during processing. Since that is the case with your `sidewaystable` page, this page is rotated in the display, and subsequently in print as well. Supplying the option distiller option `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` to Ghostscript should leave the landscape pages in their original portrait orientation.
2. Use `pdflatex` directly. This circumvents the above requirement all together.

Comment: Since my document is full of eps images, I will go for the first option. I just changed the command invoked by TexMaker for the ps2pdf instruction and everything seems to work fine. Thank you Werner and thank to the others, too!

Comment: If you use TeXLive 2011 (and maybe 2010 too) `pdflatex` convert all your .eps files in .pdf files on-the-fly during compilation. So you would be able to use it. Another way is to convert the images on your own using `epstopdf`.

Comment: @Spike: I don't think conversion is done on-the-fly. Mind you, I've always gone the route of converting from (E)PS to PDF before compiling with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @Werner I don't know if my explanation was clear but I meant exactly what you can read here (first section): http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb31-2/tb98berry.pdf
As you can read, the conversion is made by `pdflatex` itself during compilation