# Compile latex to pdf directly, skipping ps

Tags: pdf, compiling, ps

Up until now, I have been using the MikTeX compiler along with the TeXnicCenter editor to compile latex documents to pdf via ps, i.e., LaTeX ==> PS ==> PDF.

However, I recently run into the printing problem of rotated pages (using the sidewaysfigure environment) inside twosided documents, as exactly described here: [Page upside down?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31661/page-upside-down)

The question is, is it OK to compile directly to PDF, thus skipping PS, in order to have the rotated pages print properly in an easy manner? For reference, I am compiling a large document including a number of .eps figure (either vector-only or mixed vector/image content). Am I missing some functionality by skipping the PostScript creation?

Comment: eps images can't be included directly but they can be converted automatically on-the-fly as part of the compilation. If you use postscript specials in your code itself (e.g. `pstricks`) there are some limitations to what's possible if you compile directly to pdf (`pdftricks` can't replicate the full functionality). I'm assuming you are thinking of using pdfLaTeX. If you use LuaLaTeX, you can use eps files directly, I believe.

Comment: You can use `epstopdf` or `auto-pst-pdf` packages and then compile using `pdflatex.

Comment: @cfr: Can you please elaborate on the "direct inclusion" vs. "on-the-fly conversion" of .eps images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle you can switch from `.eps` files to `.pdf` without much ado, as long as there is no other direct `PostScript` code in your document, e.g. `pstricks` or `psfrag`.

The formats of `.pdf` and `.eps` files are completely different and `pdflatex` can handle inclusion of `.jpg`, `.png`, `.gif` and `.pdf` (**recognized ones**) files, but not `.eps` or `.ps` files.

In order to use such files in your `.tex` document, those `.eps` files has to be converted to `.pdf` (or one of the recognized ones). This can be done

- **either** beforehand, using a direct converter of a graphics programe or `epstopdf` perl script (see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf), ideally having a 
  file named `foo.eps` to become foo.pdf, so nothing has to be changed in `*.tex` file, as long as no direct extension is given. This means **direct inclusion after direct conversion**.
- **or** let `pdftex` or `pdflatex` do the job by converting the graphics file
  while compilation. In this case the file `foo.eps` will be converted to `foo-eps-converted-to.pdf`, having really that longer name. There is the package `epstopdf` (not to be confused with `epstopdf` perl script!), giving some options how the conversion is done etc. Automatic conversion requires the `shell-enable` feature, i.e. `pdflatex --shell-escape`. This is called **on-the-fly-conversion**

Regarding the aspects of including rotated pictures or (via `sidewaysfigure`):
Some `.eps` generators produce already rotated pictures, so they have to be either rotated again (to the other direction) or can be included correctly, depending on the particular application.

The package `graphicx` allows for `\DeclareGraphicsPath` and `\DeclareGraphicsExtension` commands.

Generally said, it is better to omit the file extension in `\includegraphics`, such that `\includegraphics` can search a list of possible extensions and include the first match. If you rather prefer to include `foo.jpg` instead of `foo.pdf`, then say `\includegraphics{foo.jpg}` explicitly.

Regarding such `PostScript` specific code from `psfrag` or `pstricks`: In my personal point of view, it is better to generate a standalone `.eps` file from that code with `latex` in an other `*.tex` document and include it in the current `.tex` file, with one of two possibilities mentioned above. In this case `pstricks` package `pst-eps` might help, in conjunction with `dvips -E -o` option.

```
\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{epstopdf}%  Not necessary, actually, please see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epstopdf-pkg


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{ctanlion.eps}  % will not work always, since restricted to `.eps`

\includegraphics{ctanlion}  % will work always, since file extensions will be added appropiately
\caption{CTAN lion draw­ing by Duane Bibby; thanks to www.ctan.org}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\begin{tabular}{l}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,angle=0]{ctanlion} 
 \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{l}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,angle=-90]{ctanlion} 
 \end{tabular} \tabularnewline
\begin{tabular}{l}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,angle=-270]{ctanlion} 
 \end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{l}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,angle=-180]{ctanlion} 
 \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\caption{CTAN lion draw­ing by Duane Bibby; thanks to www.ctan.org}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's interesting that on my setup, I compiled from LaTeX directly to PDF without using the epstopdf package. It run smoothly and with no problem. Is it because the file was already compiled beforehand via PS (i.e., LaTeX ==> PS ==> PDF)? The reason I am not using the angle option of the \includegraphics command is that I want the caption to be rotated as well, according to the orientation of the figure.

Comment: @ChrisOreinos: It works without the package, yes, because this is done by `\includegraphics` from `graphicx` package already. `epstopdf` provides some additional options and even allows for setting another `on-the-fly-converter` programme/script